# How to describe object with the only difference in typescript?

Tags: typescript, rest

I receive a pretty big object from serverside, let say

```
{
 id:'asd123',
 created: 1591605861388,
 // hundred of fields more...  
}
```

My model type actualy is the same except the "created" - this is Date.

```
type Model = {
 id: string,
 created: Date,
 ...
}
```

I need to create function that creates model of type Model

```
function x(raw:???):Model{ // intentionally simplified
 return { 
    ...raw,
    created: new Date(raw.created) 
  }
}
```

What i have to write instead of question marks?
How can i define this in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGygXigbwFBQJYIBcUAzsAE54B2A5gDS4DG5EAhsBEVACLsQMBfbNlCRYiFACZ0UAPIBbPMAA88JMjpQA5MzYcEWgHxQAZFlxRLuvlzKVaAbmxDsjOFTJQOZYmqkycSysWG2ItSQAGSIBaCIAOaIBGSS0GIPwuLWSAZi1nIA)

```
type Model = {
 id: string,
 created: Date,
}

type Model2 = Omit<Model, 'created'> & {
    created: string;
}

const test: Model2 = {
    created: '2020-08-12',
    id: '123'
}
```